# Null pointer exception when dealing with intents

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to get string arrays from two different activities passed to the same activity.

Activity A:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.media_player); 


    chosen2 = this.getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("chosenkey"); //"chosenkey" is from activity B

    songlist = this.getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("songsavekey"); //"songsavekey" is from activity C
```

Activity B:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent goToMediaPlayer = new Intent(PlaylistSelectActivity.this, MediaPlayerActivity.class);                
            goToMediaPlayer.putExtra("chosenkey", chosen);
            startActivity(goToMediaPlayer);
        }
    });
```

Activity C

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("songsavekey", songsave);
            myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

I can get each array individually if I comment out the other, but when they're together I get a null pointer exception when starting activity A. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something simple or misunderstanding something about intents, but I haven't got a clue what to look for...

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is erroneous. You cannot start the same instance of the activity from two different activities. So your onCreate will be called twice when two different intents are called. You can try this approach-

Send "songsavekey" from activity C to activity B
And then send "chosenkey" from activity B to acitivity A.
And then try to get them through intent extras.

If you do not get this, I have a more complex solution for you. :P

Answer (score 0):

if you are launching A from B, you will only get what B put in the intent. If you are launching A from C, you will only get what C put in the intent.